# Bash removing specific content from .txt string

Tags: bash

I'm currently writing a script in bash that outputs a list of domains that are currently alive and returning a 200 status code, it currently returns this:

```
https://example.com [200]
https://google.com [200]
https://facebook.com [200]
```

I'd like to remove the `[200]` from each line of the text file using bash, is this possible?

Edit:
I did search for an answer before posting, and have tried using sed `sed -i -e 's/[[200]]//g' 200.txt`, however it seemed to have no effect.

Comment: [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus, edited for more clarity.

Comment: You don't escape square brackets by doubling them. `[[200]` is a character class matching a single `[`, `2`, or `0` character (or `0`, but we already said that); the `]` after it is interpreted as a literal.

Comment: (Also, don't use `-i` until you know exactly what you are doing.)

Answer (score 1):

a pure bash solution using [parameter expansion](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```bash
line='https://example.com [200]'

echo "${line% \[[0-9][0-9][0-9]]}" # https://example.com
```

Comment: Slight alternative `${line% \[[[:digit:]]*\]}` or if you assumed a break at the last space then a minimal `${line% *}` will do.

Comment: That's a [useless use of `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) with a [quoting problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) (if there is a file named `2` or `0` in the current directory, the shell will expand the wildcard `[200]` to an alphabetized list of the matching files).

Comment: @tripleee updated